# function displays the graph depending on whether or not r

Tags: r, function, if-statement, conditional-statements, scatter-plot

I created a function that has as parameters two vectors and makes me a series of descriptive analyzes, but I want to establish that when calling the function it ask me if I want a scatter chart is displayed and displayed depending on whether I said "yes" or "no"
Thank you for your support.

Comment: `response <- scan(what="character",n=1,quiet=TRUE)`

Comment: if that works, you are encouraged to use it to write up an answer to your own question and post it ...

Comment: I have done this, but it doesn't work me:

    graphic<-function(x,y){
      cat("Do you want to see scatterplot? Yes=1 No=0")
      ans = scan(what=numeric(),nlines=1,quiet=TRUE)
     if(ans==0){
        cat("Do you want to see scatterplot of (X vs Y)=1 or (Y vs X)=0")
        ans = scan(what=numeric(),nlines=1,quiet=TRUE)
        if(ans==0){plot(x,y)}
        else if(length(ans)==1){plot(y,x)}
      }
    }